# How To Render Data From Firestore To React Native Component?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to render information from my firebase to a react native component. I started by console logging what I have done, the data is being fetched completely fine:

```
displayAllPlayers(){
    dbh.collection('Players').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data().First, doc.data().Last)
        })
    })
}
```

I then tried to add this information to my component as follows:

```
displayAllPlayers(){
    dbh.collection('Players').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            <Player key={doc.data().First} fName={doc.data().First} lName={doc.data().Last} />
        })
    })
}
render() { 
    const myPlayers = this.displayAllPlayers()
} 
return(
    {myPlayers}
)
```

However, I am unable to see anything on my screen. Any clues why?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

React works a bit differently. You need to save the async call response into the state, and then in the render loop check if the state is there, you loop trough it and print the players.

Comment: where can i see an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479717/how-do-i-render-firestore-data-in-react) that has already answered.

I quote the main points that might be useful for you:

> - Save the data to state when data loaded

```
render() { 
    const myPlayers = this.displayAllPlayers()
     let data = doc.data();
        this.setState({ data: myPlayers });  
}
```

> - And then render them as you want:

```
render() {

    let dataUI = this.state.data ? <h1>No Data</h1> : <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}</pre>;

    return (
        <div className="classname">
            <h1>... </h1>

            <div>
                <h1>UI Data</h1>
                {dataUI}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Also this is a tutorial about [Getting started with Cloud Firestore on React Native](https://invertase.io/blog/getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-on-react-native). Here is another tutorial a little more explained: [Create React Native Firebase CRUD App with Firestore](https://www.positronx.io/create-react-native-firebase-crud-app-with-firestore/).

I encourage you to check both links to have a better understanding.